# Unable to send email as parameter in URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I am writing an API to find users by `email_id`.

I am getting an error while sending the email as a parameter.

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    resources :users, only: [:show, :index] , param: :email
  end
end
```

When I am sending the email as a parameter then I got an error. The URL is http://localhost:3000/api/users/test@abc.com:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Api::UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with 'id'={:email=>"test@abc"}
```

This is my routes path:

```
api_users_url   GET     /api/users(.:format)            api/users#index
api_user_url    GET     /api/users/:email(.:format)     api/users#show
```

Comment: Can you post your show method of the controller?

Comment: class Api::UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :html

  def index
  resource = User.all
  render :json => resource.as_json
  end

  def show
   resource = User.find(email: params[:email])
 render :json => resource.as_json
  end

end

Comment: from the error, your controller is trying to find a user using its `id` and not `email`.

Comment: @OptimusPette I have override the id params as email.
resources :users, only: [:show, :index] , param: :email

Answer (score 11):

In your email there is a dot `.`, like `@gmail.com`. This dot is a problem.

By default, dynamic segments in Rails Routes do not accept dots.

That's why the result will be:

```
{
  "sender"=>"emai@gmail",
  "format"=>"com"
}
```

Instead of

```
{
  "sender"=>"emai@gmail.com"
}
```

#### Solution:

In your `routes.rb`:

```
get 'message/:sender', to: 'main#message_sent', constraints: { sender: /[^\/]+/} , as: 'message_sent'
```

The important part is **`constraints: { sender: /[^\/]+/}`**, which let's you pass a dot through the url parameter.

Answer (score 3):

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Api::UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with 'id'={:email=>"test@abc"}
```

You should change your `show` action to below

```
def show 
  resource = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  render :json => resource.as_json 
end
```

By default `find` takes `id`, so you should use `find_by`

***OR***

You can use `where`

```
def show 
  resource = User.where(email: params[:email]).first 
  render :json => resource.as_json 
end
```

Comment: Good answer.  Also `User.find_by(email: params[:email])` which I personally like.

Comment: Its just give me a null result... when I have input static value in place of params[:email] then returns result.

Comment: @user3906755 That means there is no such user with that email.

Comment: its not nil because I have checked it with if condition so if its nil then goes to else condition...  def show
   if params[:email]
    resource = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  render :json => resource.as_json
 else
  @resource = User.where(email: "priyatosh.ojha@gmail.com").first
  render :json => resource.as_json
 end

Comment: @user3906755 I mean there is no such user with the email before which you given.

Comment: I have data with the params[:email]

Comment: @user3906755 What is the value of `params[:email]`?

Comment: @user3906755 Now do you have any user with that email? I f not you wil get null result. This is what i'm trying to say.

Comment: @user3906755 You mean you have a user with email `test@r5i.com`?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on my application where I have an email as a variable in the URL. The problem was the dot from the email. Here is what I have done to fix it:

changed the `routes.rb` file:

```
get '/api/users/:email', to: 'users#show', param: :email, constraints: { email: /.*/ }
```

And of course, when you call the endpoint, the email in the URL has to be encoded:

```
ie: myemail@gmail.com => myemail%40gmail.com
```

Using curl to test it:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/users/myemail%40gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a hash with the key `email`, and in the controller you are finding the user by `id`. This is the wrong way to pass the email in URLs like this:

```
api_user_url    GET     /api/users/:email(.:format)     api/users#show
```

This is insecure. You have to make routes with a `post` request for your action and pass the parameter `"email": "test@abc"` there.
Then comes your action. Find the user by `email` instead of `id` like this:

```
@user= User.find_by_email(params[:email])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When creating questions or answers it's important to use proper grammar. That means making sure your capitalization and spelling is correct. We understand English might not be your primary language, but spelling and grammar checkers can help. http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html is a great article to read.

Comment: Well explained ... But could you please explain if I need to pass data in url then ??

Comment: Yes you can pass in the path like as : api_user_url_path(:email=>"abc@abc.xyz"). Here this will bind the email parameter to the url and pass this value.