# send email as parameter in URL in Rails Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this subject has already discussed but I can't find deeper help through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363017/unable-to-send-email-as-parameter-in-url-in-rails)

I try to create an API to find user based on the email. Unfortunately, I have this issue

I get the same issue meaning my email get cut on the "."

```
 User Load (37.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "aosidhasodih@gmuaksd"], ["LIMIT", 1]
```

I read about the advice to make sure to get the entire email and here my route now:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'robots.:format', to: 'robots#index', constraints: { sender: /[^\/]+/}
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
namespace :v1 do
  resources :user, only: [:show], param: :email
end
end
```

But it does not work. Should I move the constraints: { sender: /[^/]+/} in another part?

Answer (score 1):

In `{ sender: /[^\/]+/ }` you should use the parameter name you want to check.

Here in your case it's `email`. so following should fix the issue

```
get 'robots.:format', to: 'robots#index', constraints: { email: /[^\/]+/ }
```